# Lua Socket connection not working in Apache 2.4

Tags: windows, apache, sockets, http, lua

Apache Version : 2.4
Lua Version : 5.1
OS : Windows 7

Installed Apache and Lua in windows 7 OS, while try the below sample in Lua editor it establish a socket communication and hit the configured url, but if i run same code in Apache 2.4, it ends up with below error. Looks like something wrong at loading socket libfile

Lua Sample:

```
package.path= ';C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/?.lua;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/?/init.lua;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/?.lua;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/?/init.lua;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/?.luac'
package.cpath= ';C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/?.dll;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/?51.dll;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/clibs/?.dll;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/clibs/?51.dll;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/loadall.dll;C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/clibs/loadall.dll'
local io = require("io")
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
r, e = http.request("http://localhost:8080//refreshCache/")
print(package.path)
print(r,e)
```

Error:

```
[Mon Feb 01 10:41:53.738614 2016] [lua:error] [pid 5968:tid 980] AH02613: Error loading C:/Apache24/htdocs/var/example.lua: 
C:/Apache24/htdocs/var/example.lua:4: module 'socket' not found:\n\tno field package.preload['socket']\n\tno file 
'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\lua\\socket.lua'\n\tno file 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\lua\\socket\\init.lua'\n\tno file 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\socket.lua'\n\tno file 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\socket\\init.lua'\n\tno file '.\\socket.lua'\n\tno file 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\5.1\\lua\\socket.luac'\n\tno file 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\socket.dll'\n\tno file 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\loadall.dll'\n\tno file '.\\socket.dll'
```

Comment: Are you trying with the LuaForWindows installation?

Comment: @hjpotter92  yes installed through LuaForWindows_v5.1.4-46.exe and moved lua socket libs into it

Comment: @hjpotter92 any change required?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but not with Socket, but with another LuaSQL module, which works fine through the "lua exm.lua" console, but does not work through Apache 2.4, like you have. In the settings file httpd.conf I added:
LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so

```
<Files "*.lua">
     SetHandler lua-script
</Files>
<IfModule dir_module>
     DirectoryIndex index.lua
</IfModule>
```

In response I get:

```
error loading module 'luasql.mysql' from file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\luasql\mysql.dll':
%1 is not a Win32 application.
```

May require 64 compilation from source. Sources here: https://github.com/lunarmodules/luasql